# Django Model While User Login

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

Iam new in programming.
I need to make a model/table in django where details of a User has to save.
If the User login It will goes to registration page if he is not completed the registration,
else if he already completed the registration it will goes to home page.

What should I do?

> models.py

```
class UserReg(models.Model):
Name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
Date_of_Birth=models.DateField()
Age=models.IntegerField()
Gender=models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=GenderChoice)
Phone_no=models.IntegerField()
Mail=models.EmailField(unique=True)
Address=models.TextField(max_length=700)
District=models.ForeignKey(District,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Branch=models.ForeignKey(Branch,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Account_Type=models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=AccType)
Materials=models.ManyToManyField(Materials)
```

> views.py

```
def reg(request):
form = Userform()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form=Userform(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        Name=request.POST.get('Name')
        Date_of_Birth = request.POST.get('Date_of_Birth')
        Age = request.POST.get('Age')
        Gender = request.POST.get('Gender')
        Phone_no  = request.POST.get('Phone_no')
        Mail   = request.POST.get('Mail')
        Address  = request.POST.get('Address')
        District   = request.POST.get('District')
        Branch   = request.POST.get('Branch')
        Account_Type = request.POST.get('Account_Type')
        Materials = request.POST.get('Materials')
        obj=UserReg(Name=Name,Date_of_Birth=Date_of_Birth,Age=Age,Gender=Gender,Phone_no=Phone_no,Mail=Mail,Address=Address,District=District,Branch=Branch,Account_Type=Account_Type,Materials=Materials)
        obj.save()
        return redirect('/')



return render(request,'registration.html',{'form':form,})

def loginuser(request):
if request.method =='POST':
    username= request.POST['username']
    password= request.POST['password']
    user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request,user)
        return redirect('/')

    else:
        messages.info(request,"invalid username or password")
        return redirect('login')

return render(request,'login.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to bind UserReg to User model by adding OneToOne relation field to your UserReg model:

```
class UserReg(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   # rest of your fields
```

You can create modelForm for it:

```
    class UserRegForm(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
          model = UserReg
          fields = '__all__'
          widgets = {'user': forms.HiddenInput }
```

In reg view first check if user have UserReg object and if not go with the view:

```
def reg(request):
  if request.user.userreg:
    return redirect ('/')

  if request.method == 'POST':
     form = UserRegForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect ('/')
  else:
     form = UserRegForm(initial={'user': request.user})
  
  return render(request,'registration.html',{'form':form,})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best approach is to make a custom decorator

```
#in your UserReg add a new field User
 class UserReg(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     ...otherfields
```

don't forget to import User and instantiate the user above your UserReg model

```
 from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
  User = get_user_model()
```

Now make your migrations run these in the command line care when you do this command you will have an error if there is already rows in your database in table UserReg to avoid please delete all the database and run the commands again if they ran without error you are good to go

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate #
```

now create a new file in the same directory call it decorator.py and put this code inside which we will use to prevent user from viewing any page u want without filling his data

```
def complete_registration(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
       if request.user.userreg.exists(): # here we check if has a userreg profile if he has we could extra check if he had filled all fields if he passed return him to view
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        
       else:
        return redirect('registration') # else he didnt pass if checks redirect him to profil registration page

    return wrapper_func
```

now we made our decorator lets use it on all views we want to restrict user to visit without filling his profile

```
# lets import our newly decorator
from .decorators import complete_registration
```

lets assign the decorator to every view i want to restrict user from visiting without filling profile

```
 @complete_registration
 def viewname(request):
   return

 @complete_registration
  def anotherview(request):
     return
```